# Mule 4 adding a timestamp to a filepath location and name

Tags: mule, dataweave

```
Path folder/finename
```

[image: Path folder/finename]

So the folder name that I want to save the file in is "output" and "ScheduleTest.csv" this is the filename I like to call it, but I want to add a timestamp to it. This is on a File Write module. Does anyone know how to do that in expression mode?

```
<file:write doc:name="Write" doc:id="bba24eb0-8f63-4b6c-9c40-b5529325b4ea" config-ref="File_Config" path="output/ScheduleTest.csv" mode="APPEND">
        <file:content><![CDATA[#[output application/csv header=false --- payload]]]></file:content>
    </file:write>
```

Comment: You should not use a screenshot. Please copy the text of the XML configuration or flow.

Comment: ObjectStore doesn't has anything to do with files. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant File-Write module. I'll edit it and add the xml

Answer (score 2):

In an expression you can use DataWeave expressions to create the timestamp as needed:

```
path="#['output/ScheduleTest.csv' ++ now() as DateTime as String {format: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'} ]"
```

Comment: This will work for the filename, but i don't know how to direct it to the "output" folder where it needs to be saved, using dataweave

Comment: Using dataweave you create the name. Putting the expression in the path attribute of the file:write operation will create it. Note that expressions in the XML view go inside #[]

Comment: Updated example in answer

Comment: Thank you sooo much. You are a genius.